# HTML not rendering as written: Anchor tag being duplicated outside parent

Tags: html

I've run into a rendering issue I can't explain. I'm hoping someone can shed some light.

In its most simplified form I have the following HTML:

```
<html>  
    <body>
        <a id="anchor1" href="#">
            <div>
                <a id="anchor2" href="#">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When this actually renders in a browser the result is this:

```
<html>  
    <body>
        <a id="anchor1" href="#"> </a>
            <div>
                <a id="anchor1" href="#"> </a>
                <a id="anchor2" href="#">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice #anchor1 adjustments:

1. Its been closed in its original location, no longer wrapping around the div tag.
2. It's been copied as a standalone element just inside the div tag.

If I remove the innermost anchor tag (#anchor2) there is no rendering issue.

Can someone please explain what's going on here? I've been able to wrap div tags in anchor tags before, but for some reason this but of HTML has unexpected results. I've reviewed in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge...I've even tried Codepen.

Comment: Dump your markup into https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea: Error: Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.

From line 5, column 17; to line 5, column 41 //// Error: End tag a violates nesting rules.

From line 5, column 17; to line 5, column 41

          <a id="anchor2" href="#">Edit</. In plain English, `<a><a>foobar</a></a>` is illegal, hopefully for obvious reasons. If I click in there, how does that make any sense? Which `<a>` was clicked? Browsers make an effort to fix invalid HTML parses, so these browsers are doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an anchor `<a>` tag inside of another anchor `<a>` tag unfortunately.

Browser wouldn't know which one is clicked when a user clicks it, so browser tries to correct your incorrect implementation and closes the first anchor `<a>` tag and in turn it creates a havoc of html.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag. It's not valid HTML. A browser will do the best it can, but it's probably not going to be what you want.

Solution: don't do that.